# How can I escape fieldnames in active records in codeigniter.?

Tags: php, codeigniter

In one of my application, form fields are builded dynamically by the admin user, and the field name he gives is used to make the column name in mysql table (after processing for space and unwanted chars).

But it happens, the field name is as the mysql function keywords like `from`, `to` etc. Is there any way that I can escape the field names while using active records class in codeigniter ?

Comment: so yo want to prompt if there comes a keyword as table name or you want to skip it ?

Comment: its not the table, but columns. i cant skip the field because the problem is in a search function too which needs this field to be searched.

Comment: well column names are not recommended to be the keywords but if you want to, concatenate the column names with ` , like '`'+columnName+'`'

Comment: i tried this method, but when the query is builded by active records, the backtick is removed.

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of CI's active record Select() is to put backticks " ` " around field names, which is done expressly for this purpose, so if you load them into a select() and adjust a little you should be fine

Comment: thats oke with select. but i have problem mainly in the where condition. the backticks are not present there. i treid even concatenate with backticks while building the array, but still the problem exist.

Comment: run echo $this->db->last_query(); and show us an example of your query, so we understand what you are asking about